# How to compile several .txt files in a single excel sheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, import

I have several .txt files that I can import to (or just open as) separate excel files. In this case I want to import the data in all the .txt files to a single excel sheet, one below the other.

Comment: you could just from command line 
copy /b file1.txt+file2.txt  result.txt 
then just import that one result.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the format of the text files, you should be able to simply open them in a text editor (like Notepad, TextEdit, or GEdit), and paste them all into the same document, one after the other, then open the combined text file with Excel.

In addition, if you want to do it on the command line, the following might help.

On Linux / OS X, you can do this using cat:

```
$ cat file1.txt file2.txt > combinedFile.txt
```

On Windows, you can do it using copy:

```
C:\> copy /b file1.txt + file2.txt combinedFile.txt
```

Comment: using copy is much faster than type , depending on the file sizes and number of files  it could be an deal breaker.

Comment: np, btw, when you use copy like this you should add the /b option or it will add a SUB character at the end of each file

Comment: @CarsonDarling It's still wrong. `copy /b file1.txt + file2.txt combinedFile.txt`. The `+` is mandatory when copying multiple files so a single destination. See [copy](http://ss64.com/nt/copy.html)

Comment: Changes made, thats what I get for posting without testing on Windows. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I tried doing what you said (in Windows) but now I get an "Access is denied. 0 file(s) copied." message.
I wrote: copy /b 1.txt + 2.txt + 3.txt combinedfile.txt

Comment: It works in my home computer, but not in my work computer. Maybe I have some permissions issue. Thanks!